# Changing integer bits

Tags: c#, integer, bit

Ok, I have N = integer, P = position,V = 0 or 1
I have to change the bit at position P of integer N with the value V

I'm trying with 
N = 5 (101)
P = 2 (takes the 1)
V = 0 (has to make it a zero)
and the result is 97 (1100 0001) (should be 0000 0001)
I think the problem is from the mask because when I write it in the console its -5 (as it should be) but if I parse it, to see its bits I get an error (overflow)
the program is in the making so I'm currently working on **V = 0** so don't try with 1

Yesterday I posted a question and a lot of people posted sh*t like "this is not a question - you want us to solve u your problem"
 - No, I don't want you to solve me the problem I want to know **why after int result = mask & integerBinary; I get 97 and not 1**

```
using System;
class ChangeBit
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("(n) Type an integer: ");
        string integerLine = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
        Console.Write("(p) Type position: ");
        string positionLine = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
        Console.Write("(v) Type 0 or 1: ");
        string valueLine = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
        int value;
        int integer;
        int position;
        if (int.TryParse(integerLine, out integer) && int.TryParse(positionLine, out position) && int.TryParse(valueLine, out value)) // Try to parse the strings as integers
        {
            int integerBinary = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(integer, 2));
            int bitValue = ((1 << position) & integerBinary) >> position;
            int mask = ~(1 << position);
            if (value==0)
            {
            int result = mask & integerBinary;
            Console.WriteLine("(n) After bit conversion = {0}", result);
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("(n) After bit conversion = {0}", integer);
        }
        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: kkokosa beat me to answering this, he is absolutely correct. You should also start using the debugger and step through your programs, this makes the problems way more obvious. Also your Algorithm is way overcomplicated, its like travelling from NY to LA via Tokyo. Try to reduce the code to the necessary only.

Comment: You should use BitArray to do your stuff. Will be much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: You seem confused about binary stuff. If you want, I can teach you about it (for free, of course). Drop by on #omnimaga on efnet, and I'll do my best to teach you the basics.

Comment: I agree with Arnaud F., BitArray would be much less complicated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing binary string representation with binary integers:

```
int integerBinary = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(integer, 2));
```

after this line `integerBinary` is `101` because you have converted it from binary string representation `"101"` of `5`. After that all integers operation are invalid as such 101 makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier:

```
        if (int.TryParse(integerLine, out integer) && int.TryParse(positionLine, out position) && int.TryParse(valueLine, out value)) // Try to parse the strings as integers
        {
            BitArray a = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(integer));
            a.Set(position, value == 1);

            Console.WriteLine("(n) After bit conversion = {0}", a.GetInt32());
        }
```

With GetInt32 declared :

```
internal static class BitArrayEx
{
    internal static int GetInt32(this BitArray bitArray)
    {
        int[] array = new int[1];
        bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
integer ^ ((-value ^ integer) & (1 << position))
```

This will check if the bit is set and, if so, will change its value using the bitwise operator **^**.

Answer (score 0):

this code has two problems
first

```
int integerBinary = int.Parse(Convert.ToString(integer, 2));
```

does not need, cause the input integer is can be directly used to do logic operation,
and this line does not mean convert integer to its binary format, after this line integer  has become a different number

second

```
else Console.WriteLine("(n) After bit conversion = {0}", integer);
```

if value is 1 you still need to do some thing( if the original position is 0)

so the right code maybe

```
 if (int.TryParse(integerLine, out integer) && int.TryParse(positionLine, out position) && int.TryParse(valueLine, out value)) // Try to parse the strings as integers
            {

                int mask= (1<< position);
                int temp = mask | integer;
                int mask2 = ~((1-value)<<position);
                int result = mask2 & temp;
                result  = mask & result;
                Console.WriteLine("(n) After bit conversion = {0}", result);

            }
```